# In a Grid ,Paging Tool Bar displays All the records

Tags: datagrid, extjs4.2, pagingtoolbar

I am new to Ext Js,
Created a grid view which has paging toolbar where in i am fetching the data from a store(a json) and i am restrictong the pagelimit using proxy : {
                    type : 'ajax',
                    url : '/bills/resources/getXYZ.json',

```
                reader : {
                    type : 'json',
                    root : 'data',
                    totalProperty: 'total'
                }
            },
            pageSize: 2,
            noCache: false,
            //autoLoad: true
            autoLoad: {
                params: {

                    start: 0
                }
            }..
```

Despite of this, I still see all the records in the page ,eventhough i limited it to 2.Please help on this.
Thanks in Advance!!..

Answer (score 2):

In ExtJs paging works only if the server supports it. This means that the server must honor the parameters page, start and offset and send only pagesize ( default = 30 ) records.

For this reason, you cannot use paging with a fixed json file, but only with a webservice that sends data in json format.